# Why does current Thread not wait for other Threads before returning value?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have two Threads. In each of them I'm running a scheduler.

```
Thread one = new Thread(
    () -> scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(eventMaker, 0, 1, MICROSECONDS)
);

Thread two = new Thread(
    () -> timeChecker.schedule(timeAnalyser, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
);
```

Then I start them and invoke `join()` on them to make the method, in which they are initialized, wait for them to finish before returning the return value.

```
threads = new Thread[2];
threads[0] = one;
threads[1] = two;

for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].start();
}

for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    threads[i].join();
}

return a;
```

But still the method in which they are invoked doesn't wait for them. It returns instantly the value despite of the `join()` invokes. How can I achieve waiting for the Threads before returning?

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `scheduler` and `timeChecker` are `ScheduledExecutorService`s, your code is doing what it should be doing.

Both `schedule` and `scheduleAtFixedRate` are asynchronous in that they schedule the work to be done on a separate thread at some time in the future. Both of them return immediately.

Your two threads, `one` and `two`, are kind of pointless here. You seem to want to get the `ScheduledFuture` from the `schedule` calls and call `get` on them.

```
ScheduledFuture<?> schedulerFuture = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(eventMaker, 0, 1, MICROSECONDS);
ScheduledFuture<?> timerFuture = timeChecker.schedule(timeAnalyser, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

schedulerFuture.get();
timerFuture.get();
```

The `ScheduledFuture` returned for the call to [`schedule`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule-java.lang.Runnable-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) will return from `get` once the first execution is completed.

The `ScheduledFuture` returned for the call to [`scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate-java.lang.Runnable-long-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) will return from `get` only if it is cancelled or if the `ScheduledExecutorService` is terminated.

> Otherwise, the task will only terminate via cancellation or
>   termination of the executor.

Comment: so how can I use those `get` methods to achieve that the method returns a value just as soon as the schedulers have finished?

Comment: I solved it now by adding `while(!timerFuture.isDone()){}` before the `return`.But I guess thats no good practice. How can i solve this one better?

Comment: @testiguy What do you mean _as soon as the schedulers have finished_? For the call to `schedule`, since it'll only be executed once, use `get`. It blocks the thread until the task is complete. For `scheduleAtFixedRate`, the task is repeated, so there is no "completion".